# Does PETSc really give speedup?

Tags: parallel-computing, linear-algebra

I searched for linear solver libraries and found out about PETSc library which is considered to be a powerful and useful library. PETSc consists of implementations of various iterative methods with preconditioners and sparse matrix storing methods. All the methods are realized sequentially and in parallel using MPI.

I was very glad for the creators of PETSc. I downloaded and then installed it. However, when I started reading user's guide I encountered the following text:

```
PETSc should not be used to attempt to provide a “parallel linear solver” in an otherwise sequential
code. Certainly all parts of a previously sequential code need not be parallelized but the matrix
generation portion must be parallelized to expect any kind of reasonable performance. Do not expect
to generate your matrix sequentially and then “use PETSc” to solve the linear system in parallel.
```

I was surprised! *Did PETSc developers really parallelize only the matrix generating part? What is a benefit of using PETSc as a parallel solver if the linear system solving part runs sequentially*?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You misread the text.  The authors of PETSc are just telling you that you can't avoid [Amdahl's law](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Amdahl%27s_law).

They have done their best to parallelize every aspect of the linear solver.  But a real program is not *just* a call to a linear solver.  First *you* generate a matrix and then you pass the matrix to the linear solver.  If *your* matrix generator is slow, your whole program will be slow.

For example, suppose your original program spends 1000 seconds generating the matrix $A$ and vector $b$ and then you call a linear solver.  Your old (sequential) linear solver took 1000 seconds to find $x$ such that $Ax = b$.  Now you replace your old sequential linear solver with PETSc.  Suppose the PETSc authors did such a good job that the PETSc parallel linear solver finds $x$ in just *1* second!  Now how long does it take your program to run?  1001 seconds.  You got less than 2x speedup!  *You* need to do some work on your matrix generation code if you want to get a better speedup.

Pretty much the authors of PETSc are just telling you that a parallelized linear solver library is [not a magic bean](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Jack_and_the_Beanstalk).

Comment: you mean major benefit from using PETSc is got from generating parallel matrix rather than solving it? Suppose I will count execution time only for solving linear system, in this case ex. time will not depend whether matrix generated sequentially or in parallel. What is speedup of matrix solving part excluding matrix generating?

Comment: No.  The major benefit from using PETSc is going to come from using the Krylov solvers on huge matrices.  [The documentation says that you need about 20000 unknowns per parallel process](http://www.mcs.anl.gov/petsc/documentation/faq.html#slowerparallel).  Once you reach that point and you are on a machine with low cost communication for MPI you should get nearly linear speedups.  So with a system with 1 million unknowns, I'd expect you'd get approximately linear speedups for the solver on a server with 32 cores (4 Xeons or 4 Opterons).

Comment: (As compared to solving the same system on a single core of the same server.)  The point is: PETSc can speed up _only_ the linear solver.  Everything else is _your_ problem.